# How to run a class in workspace via Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to build an Eclipse plug-in that runs test classes in workspace.

But I couldn't manage to invoke the classes in different workspace (i.e different than the one that is used for plug-in development).

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Plugins can only access the current workspace.

Comment: ok yes but I don't want to make plug-in to run a class outside of the workspace. the thing is while i am developing the plug-in the working workspace is (obviously) different from the one that the plug-in will use.